# How can I automatically evaluate a script and put the results into an existing window after saving in Vim?

Tags: vim

My ideal scenario would be to have Vim split into two windows - first containing the script (python) that I am currently working on and the other showing the result of evaluating that script. This is what I have so far:

```
:autocmd BufWritePost *.py redir @p | execute 'silent w !python -' | redir END
```

When saving the script, the contents of the script is piped to the python command, the output of that command is stored in register p. What is the best way to get p into a new/empty buffer displayed in the other window?

Some things I have tried is `blast | normal! "pp | bfirst` (blast: new/empty buffer, bfirst: buffer containing python script) but this seems to leave me in the "output" buffer and for whatever reason I lose syntax highlighting and need to flip back and forth between the buffers to get it back. I would really like to do this all in place and avoid generating a temp dump file where I pipe the output of running the script and would prefer to avoid using any other external tools to "watch" the python script file and do something when it changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach was to use the preview window.  This allows you to always move to the correct window no matter how many windows you have.  It also allows you to "ignore" the fact that the preview window is open when you want to exit vim (you can just do `:q` rather than `:qa` for instance).

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.py call OutputWindow("python")
autocmd BufWritePost *.rb call OutputWindow("ruby")

function OutputWindow(executable)
    let filename=expand('%:p')

    " move to preview window and create one if it doesn't
    " yet exist
    silent! wincmd P
    if ! &previewwindow
        " use 'new' instead of 'vnew' for a horizontal split
        vnew
        set previewwindow
    endif

    execute "%d|silent 0r!" . a:executable . " " . filename
    wincmd p
endfunction
```

There may be a less verbose way to accomplish this but it appears to work pretty well as is.

Comment: Looks cool - will try it shortly once I get into the office. Could you explain what "%d|0r" does?

Comment: Sure.  `%d` deletes all the output that's currently in the buffer. `|` is just a command separator, and `0r!` says to start at line 0 and read in lines into the buffer from the output of the following command.

Comment: Works great! I did modify the execute to `execute "%d|silent 0r!python ". filename` to prevent the error prompt in the event of a syntax error.

Comment: I have a few modifications to make this a little more generic if you're ok with me adding those here.  I'll add the silent there too.

Comment: Done.  Let me know if you have any issues, I'll try to sort them out.