# Automatically run python code on save

Tags: python, vim, save, watch

Is there a way to automatically watch python script file and execute in it in tmux/screen each time it gets saved? I work mostly in vim and every time i want to evaluate the code it gets opened in new window so it kinda breaks the workflow. I'm asking this because i also work in Scala and sbt build tool has very neat option to do just that (run compiler/REPL on save)

Comment: If you're working in vim why not write a alias for the save function? Such as instead of :w you do :pyw (python save) that will then run the code at save? Also in VIM it shouldn't open a new window, at least it doesn't on my dev machine.

Comment: Are you running `vim` in a `screen` window, and want to run the Python script in a new window within the parent `screen`?

Comment: I use addon called ScreenShell which runs a tmux window next to vim's, all that inside global tmux instance. It just creates a split window inside it.

Comment: I like ctrl-z to background the editor then just run it manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I automatically evaluate a script and put the results into an existing window after saving in Vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388978/how-can-i-automatically-evaluate-a-script-and-put-the-results-into-an-existing-w)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to do this is, as sean and Kent suggest, to have `vim` drive it.

However, if you only "mostly" work in vim, that may not be appropriate.

The only other alternative is to write code that uses your platform's filesystem watch APIs, or, if worst comes to worst, periodically polls the file, and runs it on each update. Then just run that code under your `screen` or `tmux` (presumably with `vim` in another `screen` window).

Since I don't know your platform, I'll write a stupid polling implementation to show the idea—just remember that in real life, you'd be much better off with a tool like `inotifywatch`/`fswatch`/etc.:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import time

scripts = sys.argv[1:]
mtimes = {script: os.stat(script).st_mtime for script in scripts}
while True:
    for script in scripts:
        mtime = os.stat(script).st_mtime
        if mtime != mtimes[script]:
            subprocess.call([script], shell=True)
            mtimes[script] = mtime
    time.sleep(250)
```

Now, you can do this:

```
$ screen
$ python watch.py myscript.py
$ ^AS^A<Tab>^A^C
$ vim myscript.py
```

Comment: I work mostly on linux and fswatch was exacly what i was looking for. Thank you very much for help

Comment: @deprofundis: Wait, there's something called `fswatch` on linux? I didn't even know that… I was suggesting `fswatch` for OS X, and `inotifywatch` for linux (or maybe a wrapper like `gamin` or the `libfam` port I forget the name of, which hopefully have tools that work the same on every platform). But if there's a linux `fswatch`, and it does what you want… well, I'll take the accept even if I got it by accident. :)

Comment: i meant inotifywatch , fswatch is only available on Mac, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

It would be annoying if every time I save a py file, it gets executed automatically. Since you may edit a py file, just py class. Or pure config stuff. Anyway, if you want that to happen, you can try:

```
autocmd FileWritePost *.py exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)
```

what I have in my `vimrc` is:

```
autocmd FileType python call AutoCmd_python()

fun! AutoCmd_python()
        "setlocal other options for python, then:
    nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>

endf
```

now you could just **manually** press `<F9>` to test your current python file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nodemon.

`npm i -g nodemon`

then watch the file with nodemon to run it automatically

`nodemon --exec python main.py`

You can also clear the screen on each execution.

```
from os import system
system('clear')
```